# How do we make our C++ programs fix array index out of range by themselves?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I want to use some C++ code which is not written by me.
However, there are a lot of array index out of range in the code.
Moreover, the lengths of arrays may be not fixed; for example, they may be determined by the size of the input image.

I do not have enough budget to fix them manually, so I ask this question here.

I hope `a[i]` can be `a[0]` if `i<0` and `a[a.Length-1]` if `i>=a.Length`, but I can keep the code `a[i]`.

How do I make it?

Comment: You'll have to perform a check. There is no magically way to do it, especially if you're talking about plain old arrays, and not `vector`, which in that case you could `.at()` which does the bounds check for you.

Comment: And precisely how do you expect that to produce working code?

Comment: Do they have to be actual arrays, or can you write your own bounds-checked array class?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to trade bugs for other bugs. (If you have the time to verify that your "fix" always produces the correct result – you need to verify every array access – you should have time to fix the code.)

Comment: You could start by running it with bounds checking e.g. as with the Visual C++ compiler. Then having fixed the worst (most obvious) bugs, start writing **unit tests**. And refactor as necessary.

Comment: If the code is not written by you, and there are a lot array out of range, then you'll probably have more problems than simple "out-of-range" arrays.

Comment: No, I don't think there are way to fix your problem magically.  Or, it will not cost you less even there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a (templated) class that wrapped an array and overloaded the [] operator to perform bounds checked access to the underlying array. You could then use this class instead of normal C arrays.

How workable this will be will depend heavilly on how the application uses the array. If the array is a gloabl variable or part of a structure/class and is only ever accessed by [] then it will work great but if the array is passed arround by "degrading" to a pointer (and note that array parameters are really pointer parameters) then more work will be needed, changing parameter types and possiblly creating a seperate "checked array reference" class to be used in addition to your "checked array".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try a wrapper `class` that is initialized with the original array and then uses an `operator[]` to behave as you need.